# Can I open a file in a new split screen tab with a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In VS Code I can press command + P to search for files and then when I find the one I'm looking for I can press Command + Shift + Enter to open the file in a new tab that adds a split pane to the window.

I can browse in a similar way in IntelliJ pressing Shift twice, but I can't figure out how to open the file in a tab in a split pane, just in a new tab in the same pane on pressing Enter. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the tab line, where all of your files are tabbed and opened, you can right click and see the option `Split Vertically` and `Split Horizontally`. They will split your window as needed. You can bind these options to a macro and automatically have anything split in a second.

[image]

Then you can just open any file with your explorer, and then run your key combination to split it!

**Edit**: you can create key mapping from the `Settings` -> `Keymap` menu.

Comment: Is there really no better way here?  There isn't a keyboard shortcut to "open file in a split"?

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Robot

I think, it's too late to answer this question.
But anyways, there is already a predefined keymap binding as per your requirement to open a new file in a split window.

keymap is **Shift + Enter**

After searching any file, you just have to press this combination and it will open that new file in a split window.

*This keymap is for Mac, it may be different for other OS.